# Scanning text to a variable until a "\t" is detected

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a script that reads in a text file line by line and assigns substrings of the line to individual variables. The majority of this is already done, but I can't seem to figure out the seemingly simplest part.

**Example Text File:**

12345     Lenovo X1 Carbon     This is a comment

**Ideal Variables:**

```
String tag = "12345";

String Name = "Lenovo X1 Carbon";

String Comment = "This is a comment";
```

**Actual Variables:**

```
String tag = "12345";

String Name = "Lenovo";

String Comment = "X1 Carbon This is a comment";
```

I have all of this working, minus being able to stop reading where a "\t" should be detected. I'm using the code below to try and read in text until the tab is read (single variable example).

```
String myName = "";
while(!lineScanner.next().contains("\t"))
    myName += lineScanner.next();
```

Am I missing something simple in this?

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: What's a `lineScanner`?

Comment: You can try using line.split ("\t"); reading the full line into  variable line. This will return a String[] containing all parts of your string that were delimited by tab

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `lineScanner` is a reference to a `Scanner`, you are probably missing that a `Scanner`'s default delimiter pattern matches whitespace, and that tab characters and space characters (among others) are whitespace.  The tokens returned by a `Scanner` never include any delimiters.

You can set a `Scanner` to use a different delimiter pattern at any time via one of its `useDelimiter()` methods.  Be aware that if you later `reset()` the scanner then its pattern will be restored to the default.

Possibly you want this:

```
Pattern originalDelim = lineScanner.delimiter();
Pattern alternateDelim = Pattern.compile("[\t\n]+");

String tag;
String name;
String comment;

tag = lineScanner.next();
lineScanner.useDelimiter(alternateDelim);
name = lineScanner.next();
comment = lineScanner.next();
lineScanner.useDelimiter(originalDelim);
```

Perhaps you could use the alternative delimiter pattern all the time without switching; that depends on details of your input file format.

Comment: I know about delimiter, but seem to have had the wrong concept of it until now. Your solution worked perfectly, and gave me a better understanding of Scanner's token returns. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
    String s = lineScanner.next());
    if(s.contains("\t")) {
        //handle
        break;   //exit out of the loop
    }
}
```

Your current code calls .next() twice, so you're actually passing up on the proper input.